# Electron.remote is undefined

Tags: node.js, electron

I have trouble with using Electron. As you can see the title, when i load remote module, it saids it is undefined. This is the code of entry js:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, BrowserWindow, Tray, remote, ipcMain } = electron;

function initApp() { ... }

app.on('ready', () => {
    initApp();

    console.log(electron);         // object, but no remote inside
    console.log(electron.remote);  // undefined
    console.log(remote);           // undefined
});
```

and i tried to follow official doc here: http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/remote/

with

```
const { remote } = electron;
const { BrowserWindow } = remote;

let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});  // error! BrowserWindow is not a constructor blabla

...
remote.getCurrentWindow().focus();
```

i don't know what am i missing. any advice will very appreciate.

Comment: Are you running this code in a render process?

Comment: No, it is main process.

Comment: Well there is your problem then. `remote` is needed only to require other modules from inside a render process. In the main process just get your modules directly from `require('electron')`. Which it looks like you do, you just need to remove `remote`...

Comment: @Teak You should convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I think I misunderstood of Electron remote module, now I solved my problem. Thank you for your answer Teak. Like Vadim said, it will be good write your comment to answer.

Comment: For Electron 14 and later: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69297584/1768303

Answer (score 165, accepted):

**Update 2020**, since this answer still appears at the top. For the original answer to work in current versions of Electron, you need to set `enableRemoteModule` when creating the window in your main process.

```
const myWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        enableRemoteModule: true
    }
});
```

Original answer:

`remote` is needed only to require other modules from inside a render process. In the main process you just get your modules directly from `require('electron')`. Which it looks like is done in the example just with `remote` unnecessarily added.

Render process:

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
const { BrowserWindow } = remote;
```

Main process:

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
```

Comment: `import { remote } from 'electron';` in typescript and in renderer process throws error on windows but works fine on mac os.

Comment: I just get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'BrowserWindow' of 'remote' as it is undefined.`

Comment: Thank you so much for your thoughtful update of your answer in 2020!  I couldn't understand why my "remote" was undefined.

Comment: `enableRemoteModule: true` is what being required on newer version of Electron.

Comment: I have enableRemoteModule  set to true, but I am still facing the same error.

Comment: Electron 14 doesn't have ``enableRemoteModule: true`` property anymore, yet without it ``@electron/remote`` doesn't work as it requires that property to be set :)

Comment: Using v17 of electron. the remote prop is not available in the electron import

Comment: In electron version 27 while using remote model,my script file render.js in not loading. Unable to load preload script: /home/dev105/eclipse-workspace/TG/src/render.js (anonymous) @ node:electron/js2c/renderer_init:2

Answer (score 65):

In electron 10.0.0, `remoteModule` is set `false` by default. So, if you want to use `const {BrowserWindow, dialog } = require('electron').remote;` in JavaScript file, then you must set `enableRemoteModule` as `true` in `webPreferences`.

```
const w = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        enableRemoteModule: true
    }
});
```

link: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/breaking-changes.md#default-changed-enableremotemodule-defaults-to-false

Comment: Thanks! Really missed that ```enableRemoteModule```.

Comment: Have mercy this took me 2 days to find.

Comment: You should know `remote` is deprecated and will be removed from new versions, probably before the end of 2021.

Comment: In electron version 27 while using remote model,my script file render.js in not loading. `Unable to load preload script: /home/dev105/eclipse-workspace/TG/src/render.js
(anonymous) @ node:electron/js2c/renderer_init:2`

Answer (score 27):

The remote module was deprecated in Electron 12, and will be removed in Electron 14. It is replaced by the `@electron/remote` module.

```
// Deprecated in Electron 12:
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote
```

```
// Replace with:
const { BrowserWindow } = require('@electron/remote')

// In the main process:
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()
```

Answer (score 6):

**remote** becomes undefined sometimes in electron all you have to do is to go to your main.js and add the following object while creating a window under webPreference set **enableRemoteModule: true** as shown bellow then your problem will be solved

```
 win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 700,
    height: 600,
    hasShadow: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
     },
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

i enabled remote module, still getting

```
index.html:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getCurrentWindow')
```

for

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
```

(or)

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
```

while using

```
remote.getCurrentWindow().close();
```

i did add

```
webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
    }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: You can check answer from @Ha0ran , remote has been removed from electon's package from v14 above.