# Open file dialog from React Component using Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

So I'm aware without react on the render thread I can do this to open a file dialog.

```
const {dialog} = require('electron').remote
dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openFile']}))
```

I'm trying to use react and learn the workflows of React & Electron though. Doing the require gives me the following error.

```
TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
getElectronPath
   5 | var pathFile = path.join(__dirname, 'path.txt');
   6 | 
   7 | function getElectronPath() {
>  8 |   if (fs.existsSync(pathFile)) {
   9 |     var executablePath = fs.readFileSync(pathFile, 'utf-8');
  10 | 
  11 |     if (process.env.ELECTRON_OVERRIDE_DIST_PATH) {
View compiled
(anonymous function)
  18 |   }
  19 | }
  20 | 
> 21 | module.exports = getElectronPath();
View compiled
```

Unsure what I can do to make this work. Should be a pretty simple canvas drawing app, but i do need to enumerate images in folders & give file dialog capabilities to the app. Any ideas how to remedy this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to cast a event from the main thread and listen for it on the renderer thread?

Comment: I think it is failing because of the React pre-compiler not understanding what is going on. Not anything innately wrong with the code. I'll need to dispatch an even from the render thread to trigger it on the main thread in this situation unless I want to put it in a menu or something. Goal is to have a nice looking html button spawn the file dialog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution. You can run a preload.js into a window on creation and then call the items like javascript objects.

Found this issue on the github
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800, 
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      preload: __dirname + '/preload.js'
    }
  });
```

Preload.js

```
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;
window.electron = {};
window.electron.dialog = dialog;
```

Then anything I want to load into the window I can just add to the window.electron object and call it with no issues. React pre-compiler is more the issue than anything with electron.

Comment: I tried your solution. But I'm still getting `undefined` for the `dialog` object. I tried using the `dialog` object directly under the electron module(remove the `remote` attribute in line 1 of p`preload.js`) but it still doesn't work. Mind if you help me?

Comment: @Beast  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884130/electron-remote-is-undefined this says the require has changed with the newer versions of Electron. Replace the require in my example with require('@electron/remote') .