# Electron JS - Cannot destructure property 'BrowserWindow' of 'require(...).remote' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

**This is in Renderer Process:**

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron').remote

const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

const newWindowButton = document.getElementById('new-window-btn');
newWindowButton.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    let win3 = new BrowserWindow();
    win3.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname,'index3.html'),
        protocol: "file",
        slashes: true
    }))

})
```

**I am not able to open a new window in renderer process, getting the below error.**

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'BrowserWindow' of 'require(...).remote' as it is

```
undefined.**
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ElectronTute\helloWorld\index1.js:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ElectronTute\helloWorld\index1.js:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1145)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js`enter code here`:1166)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:881)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77)
    at index1.html:13
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron.remote is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884130/electron-remote-is-undefined)

Comment: In particular the new answers (`enableRemoteModule`)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
 mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 960,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
     },
  });
```

I believe you are using the new version of Electron. From the v9 version, we are not allowed to use `remote` on the renderer unless set the `enableRemoteModule` as true.

Plus, to load `node_moduels` on the renderer by using `require()`, we need to enable the `nodeIntegration` as well. As `require` is one of the node APIs.

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21408

For me, I'm exposing only necessary APIs via the `preload` script.

Comment: note from it. Even enableRemoteModule will be deprecated v12. You can start thinking of migration

Comment: What is the recommended upgrade path from remote?

Comment: It still doesn't work. I am using Electron version 19.0.8

Comment: Try exposing modules through preload script.