# TypeError: Cannot read property 'require' of undefined (Electron)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I need help, I am doing and learning about Electron and when I want to use 'remote' in my app.js throws me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'require' of undefined
```

This is my app.js

```
    const { ipcRenderer, remote } = require('electron'); 

    const main = remote.require('../main'); //The error is generated here
```

The location of the main.js is correct.

This is my main.js

```
const{BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

function hello(){
    console.log('Desde Main')
}

let window

function createWindow() {
    window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 799,
        height: 599,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        }
        
    })

    window.loadFile('src/ui/index.html')
    //window.removeMenu()//
}

module.exports = {
    createWindow,
    hello
}
```

If you need any more information do not hesitate to consult me, thank you very much.

UPDATE

I performed the indications shown in response ([Electron.remote is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884130/electron-remote-is-undefined)), but I throw the following error...

```
(electron) The remote module is deprecated. Use 
https://github.com/electron/remote instead.
log @ electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:13
```

And then the next

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../main.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\claur\Documents\ThomasLaurence\workspace\Metales_del_Sur_ODT\src\index.js
- C:\Users\claur\Documents\ThomasLaurence\workspace\Metales_del_Sur_ODT\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js
- 
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887)
    at Function.n._resolveFilename (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:257)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959)
    at electron/js2c/browser_init.js:221
    at IpcMainImpl.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:221)
    at IpcMainImpl.emit (events.js:315)
    at Object.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:161)
    at Object.emit (events.js:315)
```

Everything I can visualize from the console in my application window

Comment: The error occurred because the value of `remote` was `undefined`.

Comment: you may find your answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884130/electron-remote-is-undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron.remote is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884130/electron-remote-is-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official docs,

> ⚠️ WARNING ⚠️ The remote module is deprecated. Instead of remote, use
> ipcRenderer and ipcMain.

If you are using app.js to pass data between the main and renderer processes,you can declare it as a preload like so:

```
 window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 799,
    height: 599,
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: true, 
      nodeIntegration: false, 
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'app.js')
    }
```

This way, app.js will be able to access node modules too.
[Here](https://gist.github.com/malept/3a8fcdc000fbd803d9a3d2b9f6944612) is a gist that will help you understand how to pass data between renderer and main process.

Comment: Beware guys. Only some actions can be done in a preload script. For anything better, you need inter-process communication.