# Electron: Cannot read property of 'app' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to get the path for my app inside one of the HTML windows.
I have the following code:

```html
<script>
const { remote } = require('electron');
        var path = require('path');
        var appPath = path.dirname(remote.app.getPath('exe'));
        console.log(appPath)
```

I don't understand how to define app inside the html views?
This outputs the error of

```
Cannot read property of 'app' of undefined
```

Comment: is it really nodejs? it seems you have a script tag at the beggining of your code, I would assume it's in browser and if that's the case this is not how you access external libraries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron.remote is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884130/electron-remote-is-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions
Your description is too simplistic

```js
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        enableRemoteModule: true
    }
});
```

This may help you!