# enableRemoteModule is missing from Electron v14 TypeScript type definitions

Tags: typescript, electron

I've upgraded to Electron 14, refactored my project to accomodate for the ["Removed: remote module"](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/breaking-changes#removed-remote-module) breaking change, but I'm unable to compile it due to the following TypeScript error:

```
Type '{ plugins: true; nodeIntegration: true; contextIsolation: false; enableRemoteModule: true; backgroundThrottling: false; webSecurity: false; }' is not assignable to type 'WebPreferences'.

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'enableRemoteModule' does not exist in type 'WebPreferences'.ts(2322)

electron.d.ts(12612, 5): The expected type comes from property 'webPreferences' which is declared here on type 'BrowserWindowConstructorOptions'
```

The affected code:

```
const window = new electron.BrowserWindow({
    // ...
    webPreferences: { 
      plugins: true, 
      nodeIntegration: true, 
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true, 
      backgroundThrottling: false,
      webSecurity: false 
    }, 
    // ...
  });
```

Is this a bug or an intentional change in Electron v14? What's a workaround?

Comment: In case it's not clear from the answers, this is not a bug. `enableRemoteModule` is no longer available (can still use [`@electron/remote`](https://github.com/electron/remote#electronremote) , but it is deprecated). See https://github.com/electron/remote/releases/tag/v2.0.0

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Now Electron 14.0.1 is out, and this is how I could enable `remote` modules for both Main and Renderer processes (your `webPreferences` settings may vary).

First, install `@electron/remote` package (important: no `--save-dev`, as it needs to be bundled):

```sh
npm install "@electron/remote"@latest
```

Then, for Main process:

```
  // from Main process
  import * as electron from 'electron';
  import * as remoteMain from '@electron/remote/main';
  remoteMain.initialize();
  // ...

  const window = new electron.BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: { 
      plugins: true, 
      nodeIntegration: true, 
      contextIsolation: false,
      backgroundThrottling: false,
      nativeWindowOpen: false,
      webSecurity: false 
    } 
    // ...
  });

  remoteMain.enable(window.webContents);
```

For Renderer process:

```
  // from Renderer process
  import * as remote from '@electron/remote';

  const window = new remote.BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: { 
      plugins: true, 
      nodeIntegration: true, 
      contextIsolation: false,
      backgroundThrottling: false,
      nativeWindowOpen: false,
      webSecurity: false 
    } 
    // ...
  });

  // ...
  // note we call `require` on `remote` here
  const remoteMain = remote.require("@electron/remote/main");
  remoteMain.enable(window.webContents);
```

Or, as one-liner:

```
require("@electron/remote").require("@electron/remote/main").enable(window.webContents);
```

It's important to note, if created from a Renderer process like that, `BrowserWindow` is a [remote object](https://github.com/electron/remote#remote-objects), i.e. a Renderer proxy to a `BrowserWindow` object created inside the Main process.

Comment: Thanks, the one-liner does the trick in my case

Comment: Wish I could upvote this again. I've crawled through too many stale threads to reach this